# Find Laurent expansion of $\frac{1}{\sin z^3}$ at $0 < ∣z-\sqrt[3]{2 \pi}∣ < ∣\sqrt[3]{4 \pi} - \sqrt[3]{2 \pi} ∣$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need to find the principal part of the Laurent expansion of the function in the annulus described in the title.

In my attempt, I have replaced $z$ by $w:=z - \sqrt[3]{2 \pi}$. I know the Taylor expansion of the $\sin$ function. I have tried to use a approach similar to the one used in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778686/finding-the-first-four-terms-of-the-laurent-series?rq=1), where we know $g(z)$ and try to compute coefficients one by one of the function $f(z):=1/g(z)$ using the fact that $f(z)g(z)=1$.

One of the doubts I am having with this method is: why can we write such an $f$ without negative powers of $z$? If I can do that in our example then I guess all of the negative coefficients are equal to $0$... Can you please help me clarify and give some hints to the needed computation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If $g(z):=(z-a)f(z)$ is holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $a$ the principal part consists of just one term $g(a)/(z-a).$ The value $g(a)$ can be calculated as the limit  $\lim_{z\to a}(z-a)f(z)$

Comment: Thank you for your answer @RyszardSzwarc. In your notation, $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sin z^3}$ and $a=\sqrt[3]{2 \pi}$ right? I will try to use your hint although computing the complex limit does not seem an easy task..

Comment: Exactly. Calculate the reciprocal of the limit and notice that it has the form of the derivative of the function $\sin(z^3)$ at $a.$

Comment: Is the final answer $c_{-3}=1/3$ and $0$ for all other coefficients corresponding to negative powers? I am trying some other approach now..@RyszardSzwarc

Comment: No. I got $c_{-1}={\sqrt[3]{2\pi}\over 6\\pi}.$ It seems that you calculated the Laurent expansion at $0,$ not at $ \sqrt[3]{2\pi}.$ By the way, at $0$ the result would be $c_{-3}=1.$

Comment: Dear @RyszardSzwarc I finally got some answer that makes sense. I agree that there is only one non zero coefficient in the principal part, but I go that $c_{-1}=3(\sqrt[3]{2 \pi})^2$. Are you sure of your answer?

Comment: I got the reciprocal $${1\over 3(\sqrt[3]{2\pi})^2}= {\sqrt[3]{2\pi}\over 6\pi}$$

Comment: My apologies, I meant that!. Did it. Thank you!